# ValueError: Input 0 of layer conv2d_6 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=4, found ndim=1. Full shape received: [None]

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0, conv-neural-network

I've checked many of the similar replies over here for some other codes but, they could not help me somehow. It might help me if I ask the problem with code here. I would be pleased if someone could help me out.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Dropout
import numpy as np

X = np.load("feature.npy") #loading X
y = np.load("feature.npy") #loading y

X = X/255

model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3), input_shape=X.shape[1:]))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Flatten())  # this converts our 3D feature maps to 1D feature vectors

model.add(Dense(64))

model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X, y, batch_size=32, epochs=3, validation_split=0.3)
```

As it says it needs 4 dimensions, So I made it 4d.

`model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3), input_shape=(64,64,1)))`
I added only 3 because tensorflow adds another by itself. But it says

`ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_10_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (24946, 1)`

Comment: What is X.shape?

Comment: X.shape=(24946,)

Comment: That's your issue. You need x to have the correct shape for an image, reshape it to have 4 dimensions. (n, y, x, c).